# Perc H700: Rebuild RAID array manually

Tags: raid, dell-perc, raid10

I have a RAID 10 array on Perc H700 RAID controller in a R510 lab server. One of the disks in the RAID array failed. Since it's a lab box and I don't need to worry about down time, I just shut it down, pulled out the failed drive, and put in the new one.

In hindsight I think it would have been easier to just hot-plug in the new drive and it would have rebuilt itself.

But now the raid controller just shows the degraded RAID array, and a separate unconfigured drive that is not part of the array.

I have access to the controller through either the BIOS or the `perccli64` tool. I don't know how to add the new drive to the degraded array and get it to rebuild itself.

Comment: Have you tried setting the replacement drive as a global hot spare?

Comment: @JimNim I have not.. Is that the normal way to do this?

Comment: @JimNim I always thought of the global hot spare as something that would need to be configured _before_ the drive fails.

Comment: From the PERC BIOS, yes - it's about the only way once you've removed the failed drive and inserted a replacement. Just jump to PD Mgmt, select the drive, F2 and "Make Global HS"

Comment: @JimNim Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the answer from comments...

A PERC won't auto-rebuild to a newly inserted drive. You must "tell" it that you want to rebuild to the replacement drive, which is easily accomplished by making the replacement drive a global hot spare. Once assigned, the rebuild should start automatically.